# set opacity to child div with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a fadeout/fadein loop in plain/raw javascript however it seems like i can´t get the simpliest thing to work. The opacity filter itself. i have a `div id="slideshow"` and creating 2 dynamic childs. `Img and div`

```
<div id="slideshow">
//start dynamic part
<img src="image1.png" />
<div id="tooltip" />
//stop dynamic part
</div>
```

im creating these tags with javascript.

```
var slideshow = document.getElementById('slideshow');
slideshow.innerHTML ='<img src="image1.png" /><div id="tooltop"></div>':
```

im now trying to to give `Slideshow`´s child div opacity using javascript.

```
var slideshowDiv =  document.getElementById("slideshow").getElementsByTagName("div");
slideshowDiv.style.opacity = 0.5;
slideshowDiv.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=50)";
```

is this not working becouse lack of eventhandler when new tags is created with javascript? else i dont understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementByTagName` returns a `NodeList` and not a `HTMLElement`.

Use index to retrieve a element from the `NodeList`.

For example, for the first element, you can do:

```
slideshowDiv[0].style.opacity = 0.5;
slideshowDiv[0].style.filter = "alpha(opacity=50)";
```

Index starts from 0 and the last index is (length of array - 1    )

Comment: so basicly a NodeList is an array? and in my case i would want to target the div which in case is slideshowDiv[1]?

Comment: @user3721495 no. It is only `slideshowDiv[0]` as you have only one `div`. `slideshowDiv` contains only divs

Comment: yeah thats true becouse i target the child div in parent. Thanks